# Properties of continuous functions with $f(x) > x$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)>x$. prove or disprove whether $f$ is monotonically increasing or not.

I tend to think it is, but have no idea to prove it. Can anyone give me some hints or a counterexample?

If $f$ is not increasing in $\mathbb{R}$, how about we restrict it to $[0,\infty)$.

By the way, does this type of function have a name? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x)=1+x^2$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $f(x) = x+2\cos(x)+2$ ?

Comment: OMG, after seeing your answer, I realized I have asked a silly question.